# Why doesn't my Android SDK manager load sample code packages

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, eclipse-adt

I'm a little frustrated with this issue,

1st: I tried opening the recent ADT (26.x.x) and failed to open the SDK manager. Is it even possible to install it?

2nd: I downloaded v25.x.x and to my advantage the SDK manager opened just fine, however, it loads all platform tools and extras but excludes platform sample code package. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your gradle file to determinate which `compileSdkVersion` you use.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Oxygen without a gradle file.